# alert for not meeting browser requirements - detecting legacy browsers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In a web application I want to create an alert that tells a user the he does not meet the minimum browser requirements. How would I go about this? Is this simple javascript? can this be done wih angular?

Update:
Sorry I need to better clarify my question. I need to detect legacy browsers in order to force the user to upgrade or let them know some features may not work due to the version of a browser they are using. I know how an alert() works but I need to detect like IE9 or lower, and as well as other browsers. I keep reading about browser detect and feature detect. I am just looking for best practices and something that is easy to maintain as browser versions change.

Comment: something like this? `alert('Do you even browser?');`

Comment: You'll have to define what you mean by *the minimum browser requirements*

Comment: Yes, it's very simple to create an alert (as shown in my first comment). You can also create nicer looking dialog messages using jQuery UI's Dialog or Bootstrap's modal, for example. If you're still looking into detecting features from a given user's browser, I'd suggest using Modernizr.

Comment: do you have a set of browsers in mind which are not recommended for your users?

Answer (score 0):

To detect OS,  Browser and Device you can use [this](https://github.com/srfrnk/ng-device-detector) library call **ng-device-detector**

In this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/urqMI1?p=preview) you can see how it works. Basically you have an object tha contain raw values like OS, browser and devices indicating with true or false.

**HTML**

```
 <script src="https://rawgit.com/srfrnk/ng-device-detector/master/ng-device-detector.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div device-detector>Using classes:</div>

  <br/>

  <div device-detector id="os-windows"></div>
  <div device-detector id="os-mac"></div>
  <div device-detector id="os-ios"></div>
  <div device-detector id="os-android"></div>
  <div device-detector id="os-linux"></div>
  <div device-detector id="os-unix"></div>
  <div device-detector id="os-firefoxos"></div>
  <div device-detector id="browser-chrome"></div>
  <div device-detector id="browser-firefox"></div>
  <div device-detector id="browser-safari"></div>
  <div device-detector id="browser-opera"></div>
  <div device-detector id="browser-ie"></div>
  <div device-detector id="device-android"></div>
  <div device-detector id="device-ipad"></div>
  <div device-detector id="device-iphone"></div>
  <div device-detector id="device-ipod"></div>
  <div device-detector id="device-blackberry"></div>
  <div device-detector id="device-firefoxos"></div>

  <br/>

  <div>{{deviceDetector}}</div>
```

**JS**

var app = angular.module('plunker', ["ng.deviceDetector"]);

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ["$scope","deviceDetector",function($scope,deviceDetector) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.deviceDetector=deviceDetector;
}]);
```